# Center align an svg to a button with grey background

Tags: html, css, button, svg, styling

I have a button with an image which I want to align to the center . I want the button to have a grey background.

HTML:

```
 <button type="submit" data-target="#modal">
            <img className="rainbow" role="presentation" />
 </button>
```

CSS:

```
.rainbow {
  background: url("/static/icons/arrow.svg") no- repeat center;
  border: none;
  cursor:pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline:none;
  height: 53px; 
  width: 50px;  
  background-color: $welcome-gray-1;
}
```

[image: final_image_button]

[icon_center_aligned](https://1fichier.com/?2fr0kjk8rbz93wpw656y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to have an inline image and you need to apply the background to the button element.

```css
button {
  background: #000 url("/static/icons/arrow.svg") no-repeat center;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  height: 53px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" data-target="#modal" />
```